# Android App to talk to a web server, download a file and parse

Tags: android, csv

I am new to this. I have the Android SDK installed with Eclipse. I can work with basic activities and layouts.

I am looking to write this Android application that will;

1) Allow users to sign-in using a pre-allocated password.

2) Login and change the password.

3) Every time the user opens the app, he downloads a CSV file from a server to the SD card.

4) The app parses from the file and displays them on several activities and small frames inside the app.

Think of it as an informational application. But, I'd like to add some intelligence on top of it after I get this done.

I have read many articles and topics but none of them give me a specific approach to do this faster. I have very little time for development. 
If there's a similar application that you're familiar with, I'd like to take a look at the code.

I want to know exactly (the code) on how the communication between the app and a linux based server on the web needs to be established. Right now, there's only a CSV file (or an EXCEL file - which one's better to parse? How to decide?) there.

Also, when the CSV file is up to date, I wouldn't want it to download the file again. How to prevent it?

As I said, I am new - so please be patient.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to this and want to develop something fast, why do it the hardest way, in java? There are so many easy toolkits out there, e.g. [RFO.Basic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rfo.basic&hl=en), you will be amazed how much you can achieve, fast, that way.

Answer (score 0):

(You asked several questions) Easiest to parse? If you don't have Excel installed on your Android device, the CSV is of course easier to parse, needing only text tools. However, if you have a choice of formats, why not use XML? If you have never worked with XML, there is a little learning curve, but there are lots of tutorials on the web. After that, you'll never want to go back to CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Your last question: how to prevent download of unchanged file? Is this about a big file? In that case start with quickly downloading the hash (checksum) of the file, so that the client can decide if the file has changed.